# How to dynamically set id to ajax.Actionlink in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a list of items and in each item I have a Ajax.ActionLink what I want to do is to set id of each action link dynamically (Item id).

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Join","ajaxview",new{    id = tour.TourId},newAjaxOption   
HttpMethod = "GET",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "currentaction"},new{
@class= "tm-tours-box-1-link-right",
@id="currentaction"})
```

my model is

**HolidayPlanners.Models.Tour**

what I want to do is something like this

```
@class= "tm-tours-box-1-link-right",
@id=@Tour.id
```

but it is giving me errors because I am using razon syntax(server side) inside jquery(client side) is there any way around to this?

Comment: Hey its not clear what error you are getting. Is the page giving a server error so it cant load? Is jquery giving some kind of error? where are you implementing jquery with this? It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic action link ajax, as I posted prior:

```
 @car.CarMake,
                               "getUpdate",
                               new { carId = car.CarId },
                               new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    UpdateTargetId = "result" + car.CarId, //use car.ID here? not sure
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    HttpMethod = "GET"
                                }, new { @class = "getClick" })
```

Model:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.Controllers.CarModel>
```

More about my model:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string theCarModel { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult getUpdate(int carId)
    {
        CarModel carModel = new CarModel();
        switch (carId)
        {
            case 1:
                carModel.CarId = 1;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated11111Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated11111Model";
                break;
            case 2:
                carModel.CarId = 2;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated2Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated22222Model";
                break;
            case 3:
                carModel.CarId = 3;
                carModel.CarMake = "updated3Make";
                carModel.theCarModel = "updated33333Model";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return PartialView("_PartialView", carModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Index700()
    {
        IList<CarModel> carModelList = Setup();
        return View(carModelList);
    }

    private static IList<CarModel> Setup()
    {
        IList<CarModel> carModelList = new List<CarModel>();
        carModelList.Add(new CarModel { CarId = 1, CarMake = "VW", theCarModel = "model1" });
        carModelList.Add(new CarModel { CarId = 2, CarMake = "BMW", theCarModel = "model2" });
        carModelList.Add(new CarModel { CarId = 3, CarMake = "Ford", theCarModel = "model3" });
        return carModelList;
    }
```